# Type 'Array[]' is not assignable to type '[Array]'

Tags: arrays, typescript

This error keeps bugging me while I'm trying to get a grab on typescript. Can anyone explain what is the difference between the two 'array'? Is any of this not an array? If not, what is it then?

```
[ts] Type 'AppointmentItemData[]' is not assignable to type '[AppointmentItemData]'.
       Property '0' is missing in type 'AppointmentItemData[]'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first type (`AppointmentItemData[]`) is an array of `AppointmentItemData` elements, while your second type is [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), that may only ever contain a *single* `AppointmentItemData`.  Quoting from [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> Tuple types allow you to express an array where the type of a fixed number of elements is known, but need not be the same. For example, you may want to represent a value as a pair of a `string` and a `number`:
>
> ```
> // Declare a tuple type
> let x: [string, number];
> // Initialize it
> x = ["hello", 10]; // OK
> // Initialize it incorrectly
> x = [10, "hello"]; // Error
> ```

Typescript allows you to encode that "this variable should only every have a 3 element array in it, where the first element is a number, the second is a string, and the third is a Promise that will eventually resolve to something shaped like a `Lizard`", whereas if it didn't the only way to encode `[number, string, Promise<Lizard>]` would be `{}[]` (that is, roughly, an `Object[]`).

Comment: Thanks Sean! Can you help me with an example of Tuple's usages. It sounds to me that tuple have the similar structure of a javascript object.

Comment: Tuples are arrays with heterogenous values - you **can** view `[1, 'hi', someSalamander]` as an object (e. g. `{0: 1, 1: 'hi', 2: someSalamander}`), but it *is* an array.  That is, `thingTypedAsTuple instanceof Array === true`.  As to how you'd use it - anywhere you want to carry around a series of things as opposed to a set of named things.  Some examples include `[success, error]`, `[value, validations]`, and `[x, y, z]`.