# Typescript Interface[] vs [Interface]

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to assign an Array of `Article` to my mongoose document, but it seems Typescript doesn't like that and I don't know why it's showing this warning/error that it's not assignable.

My mongoose Schemas and interfaces (simplified):

```
interface Profile {
  username: string,
  articles: [Article]
}

interface Article {
  index: number,
  name: string,
}

// Mongoose model
export interface IProfile extends Profile, Document { }
const Article = new Schema({
  index: { type: Number, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
}, { _id: false })

const Profile = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, index: true },
  upcomingChests: { type: [Article] },
}, { timestamps: true })

export const Profile = model<IProfileModel>('IProfile', Profile)
```

**My code trying to assign Articles:**

```
const profile: Profile = values[0]
const articles: Array<Article> = values[1]
profile.articles = articles // Error/Warning pops up in this line
```

> [ts] Type 'Article[]' is not assignable to type '[Article]'.
>   Property '0' is missing in type 'Article[]'.

**My question:**

Why does it say it's not assignable and what's the difference between [Article] and Article[] at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Array\[\]' is not assignable to type '\[Array\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697919/type-array-is-not-assignable-to-type-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Article]` means something different: a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type with 1 Article element.

You may wanted to use `Article[]`, the same type to `Array<Article>`.

Comment: So I am supposed to change the interface for Profile so that it says `articles: Article[]` is that correct?

Comment: I cannot say much about your actual data, but that should fix type mismatch (and is more likely to be used here).